# Continuously get data from field and insert into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravityforms

I need continiously get actual data (sum of calculation) from gravity form field and insert this data to div element. My code look like this

```
<html>
<header>
      Price per month:
<div id="Test_1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var permonth = jQuery('#input_54_126').val();
     jQuery("#Test_1").html(permonth);
</script>
</header>
</html>
```

I don't see any error log in console but div element is empty.
Pleasy advice how can I change code.

Comment: Have linked jquery in your document? If this your actual code, the jquery file does not seem to be linked in the document.

Comment: @zipkundan jquery already installed on site

Comment: you want to put your script code into an 'change' event handler so it gets called each time the value inside the input changes. https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

so the code above will only trigger once, on load of the script tag it is placed in. This means that whatever is in the form when the script loads will be placed in the `div` element. This is most likely an empty string to begin with.

What you want to do, most likely, is watch the input field for any changes to it. You could take advantage of JQuery's keyup event: https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

This will allow you to trigger a callback function, per each instance of the keyup event. Here you can get the value of the input and populate the `div` with it.